# MongoDb operator not working for array of object properties

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am facing a problem with `MongoDB` query. Our collection named is `products` and the data is placed something like this.

```json
    {
      "_id":"61b823681975ba537915cb0c",
      "salesInfo":{
        "_id":"61b823681975ba537915c23c",
        "salesDate":[
          {
            "_id":"61b3aa4a7b04b30cd0a76b06",
            "salesQuantity":100,
            "soldPieces":36,
            "holdPieces":0
          },
          {
            "_id":"61b3aa4a7b04b30cd0a75506",
            "salesQuantity":100,
            "soldPieces":36,
            "holdPieces":0
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

I want to add a new `field` named `percentageSold` inside an array of objects, and the value should be the calculation of the following formula `((soldPieces + holdPieces) / salesQuantity * 100)`.

My query is this but it is returning `null` for the `percentageSold` property.

```js
    db.products.aggregate( [
       {
         $addFields: {
           "salesInfo.salesDate.percentageSold": {$divide: [{$add: ["$salesDate.soldPieces", "$salesDate.holdPieces"]}, {$multiply: ["$salesDate.salesQuantity", 100]}]}
         }
       }
    ])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `salesInfo.salesDate` is an array field, you need to to use array operator like `$map` to perform element-wise operation.

```js
db.products.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "salesInfo.salesDate": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$salesInfo.salesDate",
          "as": "s",
          "in": {
            "_id": "$$s._id",
            "salesQuantity": "$$s.salesQuantity",
            "soldPieces": "$$s.soldPieces",
            "holdPieces": "$$s.holdPieces",
            "percentageSold": {
              $divide: [
                {
                  $add: [
                    "$$s.soldPieces",
                    "$$s.holdPieces"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $multiply: [
                    "$$s.salesQuantity",
                    100
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gug6lMUUBL5) for your reference.

Comment: Thank you, for answering this question. Can you please explain this query to me I mean what is `as` and double dollar sign?

Comment: @VenNilson `$map` is basically iterating the array and transforming the elements one-by-one. `$$s` is the variable I assigned for the individual array element, as specified in `"as": "s"` clause. For the `in` clause, I specified the transformation/output, which contains both the original fields and the `percentageSold` field. You can read more about `$map` in [this official document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)